# All Site Permissions for jnlp web start file for Mac Yosemite

Tags: java, macos, security, jnlp

I am using a WebStart file, launched with a jnlp file.  Actually downloaded it locally.  I used the same jnlp file on a windows machine, I changed the permissions through the `java.policy` file.  The same file works on Windows but I get accessed denied ever messages on the Mac machine.  I changed all of the `java.policy` files I can change including local but still I get the same error.  I restarted the machine several times but same error message.  Also, inside the jnlp file is `AllPermission` setting but still doesn't work.

Are there any thoughts to correct this?

JNLP security in `java.policy`, `.java.policy`.

```
grant {
        permission java.security.AllPermission;
};



  <security>    
    <all-permissions />
  </security>
```

Error Message:

```
!MESSAGE access denied ("java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission" "suppressAccessChecks")
!STACK 0
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission" "suppressAccessChecks")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:457)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:884)
```

From a permission standpoint, I am testing `AllPermissions` and then adding granular permissions as needed but I wanted to get this working.

I don't know about the 'signing' of the jar code and the app.  The jnlp WebStart file and code does work from a windows environment.

Comment: did you try adding grant  {
    permission java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission "suppressAccessChecks";
}; this might help

Comment: I will try that in the local .java.policy file  but grant { permission java.security.AllPermission; }; works for Windows.